# Can not connect to AWS Redis Cache with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

There are two nodes on AWS and I am using spring-boot 2.2.6 release.

```
@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory( String hostname, String password) {

//List<String> nodes = Collections.singletonList(hostname+":6379");
RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration()
       .clusterNode("cf-xxx11xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com",6379)
       .clusterNode("cf-xxx22xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com", 6379);
redisClusterConfiguration.setPassword(password);
 LettuceClientConfiguration lettuceClientConfiguration = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().disablePeerVerification().build();

LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration, lettuceClientConfiguration);


return lettuceConnectionFactory;
}
```

When spring boot came up, the exception showed as following:

```
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisException: Cannot retrieve initial cluster partitions from initial URIs [RedisURI [host='cf-xxxx11.cache.amazonaws.com', port=6379]]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.tryFail(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:143) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.ClusterTopologyRefresh.loadViews(ClusterTopologyRefresh.java:105) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.doLoadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:865) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.loadPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:838) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.initializePartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:813) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient.getPartitions(RedisClusterClient.java:823) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.ClusterConnectionProvider.getConnectionAsync(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.ClusterConnectionProvider.getConnectionAsync(ClusterConnectionProvider.java:40) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettuceConnectionProvider.java:53) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:1197) ~[spring-data-redis-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 94 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR This instance has cluster support disabled
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:135) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:108) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:120) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:111) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.topology.TimedAsyncCommand.complete(TimedAsyncCommand.java:51) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandWrapper.complete(CommandWrapper.java:59) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.complete(CommandHandler.java:654) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:614) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:565) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1486) ~[netty-handler-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1235) ~[netty-handler-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1282) ~[netty-handler-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:498) ~[netty-codec-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:437) ~[netty-codec-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.48.Final.jar:4.1.48.Final]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Googled a lot and did not find the solution. Could it be setting SSL or TLS issue? Tried to set lettuceConnectionFactory properties but they did not work.

Comment: Have you enabled cluster mode on aws elasticache redis? You do It when creatina the cluster

Comment: It is cluster mode disabled.

Comment: So that is the problem. This issue raises when cluster-enabled property is disabled and you try to use It as cluster. Try to enable cluster mode and see If problem goes away

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing the problem. I used RedisStaticMasterReplicaConfiguration and is able to connect. I need have mode changed on AWS by admin then try out above code. You are really helpful!!!

Comment: You're welcome @junzi ! I'll put this as an answer to the question!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the redis's configuration cluster-enabled is set with value yes. In the case of AWS redis It is enabled on aws console on cluster mode configuration.

This issue raises when this configuration is disabled, because os trying to connect as cluster on an instante that is not enabled to handle this.